# How can you get Hitman 2 to work in normal speed gameplay?

Tags: hitman-2-silent-assassin

I've been play Hitman 2 on another computer and it worked fine, but when I moved the game to another computer, the game was still working fine, except gameplay was slow motion. How can I fix this?

Comment: This sounds like an anti-piracy measure. There's a element in Mirrors Edge that if it thinks it's a pirate copy that the person you play as will not run in areas where speed is needed to cross a gap.

Answer (score 1):

Install it on the other PC instead of moving it. You will need the original software, otherwise you will have this happen again.